# Why do explicit protocols in python not require attribute implementation for @runtimechecks, but implicit protocols do?

Tags: python, protocols

If a protocol is implemented with a required attribute i.e. `name`

```
@runtime_checkable
class DuckProtocol(Protocol):
    """Protocol for a duck"""
    name: str
    @abstractmethod
    def quack(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

a runtime check of `isinstance` on an implicit subtype will fail if there is no `name` attribute, but an explicit one will not:

```
class Duck1(DuckProtocol):
    def quack(self):
        print('quack')
        
class Duck2:
    def quack(self):
        print('quack')

class Duck3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'duck3'
    def quack(self):
        print('quack')

print(isinstance(Duck1(), DuckProtocol))
print(isinstance(Duck2(), DuckProtocol))
print(isinstance(Duck3(), DuckProtocol))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

Why does this attribute check not extend to explicit subtypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Duck1()` does not follow the spec defined by the `DuckProtocol` protocol, but it is still an instance of the protocol class in the usual sense of objects being instances of classes: its type is `Duck1`, which is a subclass of the `DuckProtocol` class. By the default rules of `isinstance`, that makes `Duck1()` an instance of `DuckProtocol`.

Runtime-checkable protocols define their own `isinstance` logic (by implementing [`__instancecheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__)), but if that logic doesn't decide the object is an instance of the protocol, it ends by [delegating to `super().__instancecheck__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Lib/typing.py#L1113) instead of returning `False`. After a whole bunch more indirection and delegation, we eventually end up in `_abc._abc_subclasscheck`, which [checks for concrete subclasses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Modules/_abc.c#L686) as step 4 of its handling, and this check returns `True`.

Comment: Interesting, it makes sense that the explicit implementation is by definition an instance of the parent class. However this behavior still seems unexpected for the purpose of python protocols, is there a better method for ensuring objects have a set structure?

Comment: @mjohnson56: If you're unhappy with this Protocol behavior, I think your best option is to handle it manually.

Comment: So the answer to mjohnson's question is "No"?  This is the best I can assume given how user2357112 dodged.  I have to agree, this behavior is unexpected for anyone who comes from a more sane implementation of static interface checking.  If anyone does have a better idea of how this can be automated (because it _should_ be automated), I would love to know about it, please.